# Change TinyMCE Default Image Dimension

Tags: tinymce, plone

After selecting an Image from 'Image list', there shows the image 'Preview' and
a 'Dimensions' dropdown, with default value 'Original' selected.
How do I set selected default to 'Preview (400x400)' and therefore have 'myPhoto.png/image_preview' for HTML content.

[image]

Comment: Hi marr, TinyMCE doesn't come with any image management options like the screen shot you included. It doesn't even look like the MCEImageManager from MoxieCode, but may be an earlier version. You need to identify who supplied this feature and ask them. Cheers, Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside the TinyMCE egg at Products/TinyMCE/skins/tinymce/plugins/ploneimage/ploneimage.htm.pt

Change this line (95):
`<option tal:repeat="item portal_tinymce/getImageScales" tal:attributes="value item/value" tal:content="item/title" />`
to:
`<option tal:repeat="item portal_tinymce/getImageScales" tal:attributes="value item/value; selected python: 'Preview' in item['title']" tal:content="item/title" />`

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE use Plone global image handling settings for image scaling/tag render. Look for it at Controlpanel > Image handling.

Url address should be $YOUR_PLONE_URL/@@imaging-controlpanel